# the input shape of array about Keras on Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a question about the 4D tensor on keras about Convolution2D Layers.

The Keras doc says:
4D tensor with shape: (samples, channels, rows, cols) if dim_ordering='th' or 4D tensor with shape: (samples, rows, cols, channels) if dim_ordering='tf'.

I use 'tf', how about my input? When I use `(samples, channels, rows, cols)`, it is ok, but when I use `(samples, rows, cols, channels)` as input, it has some problems.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In order to help us answer your question, please share a little more information about the problems you encountered when using the `"tf"` ordering.

Comment: I got the answer from the author of keras on github.

Comment: Can you please share his answer then? You can put it as an answer here to your own question. That will help others who face similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

`Keras` assumes that if you are using tensorflow, you are going with `(samples, channels, rows, cols)`